# Tag in Git commit summary?

Tags: git, commit-message

Do people use tags in commit in the one line commit summary?

Are there any standard tags or commonly used tags?

Git has supports for "[tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)" but it seems to mostly be used for tagging versions like "v1.8.5-rc1".
By "tag" I don't mean that to tag a commit or a branch like "v1.8.5-rc1" for example.

MediaWiki can tag edits as [minor](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Minor_edit) signified by **m**, and bot edits by **b**.

Do people put tags in commit message?

Example:

```
[trivial] Add 'foo()' method to 'Bar' class
[minor] Add 'foo()' method to 'Bar' class
[wip] Add 'foo()' method to 'Bar' class
```

- Do people use tags such as this?
- Is it common practice?
- Are these called tags, or what are these called?
- Are there any standard tags?
- Are there any commonly used tags?
- What tags are in common use?
- What is the syntax, is it a word enclosed in square brackets?

Comment: `git` has no opinion about how you structure commit messages; teams set conventions, and can enforce those using hooks. To the extent that some conventions are commonly used, you may want to look them up for consideration; but the way the question is framed... there is no "standard" from `git`'s perspective. However, `git` *does* have a particular terminology, and things get confusing when a term `git` defines is used with `git` in a way that conflicts with the `git` definition... so please when using `git` (or, really, any source control system I know of), don't call what you're doing a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git commit message conventions are multiple.
**Everything depends on what you want to do with it.**

I would say that name for this is simply "commit message convention" or more precisely for your use case "commit message labeling".

One is the [Angular convention](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#commit), that use "type" which is one of:

- feat (feature)
- fix (bug fix)
- docs (documentation)
- style (formatting, missing semi colons, …)
- refactor
- test (when adding missing tests)
- chore (maintain)

Some other use [different/more types](https://github.com/kazupon/git-commit-message-convention), and even [emoji](https://gitmoji.carloscuesta.me/) to add commit info in message.

It's up to you to define your own commit message convention (or use an existing one).
If you want to generate a changelog from commit messages, convention must be well defined and format must allow automatic parsing

---

As you discovered, git ["tag"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) notion is totally different and is a way to name a specific commit, mostly used for releases.

---

BTW, there are some bad practices in your example:
- "WIP" notion should be in a branch
- Commit message should answer the question "Why?" not "What?" (the `git diff` already give this information. Take a look at "[A Note About Git Commit Messages](http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html)"